# Using RPi as a 4g enabled dropbox usb stick

Tags: usb

First of all hello, I am exceptionally new to the concept of the Rasberry, however I have an application that I am hoping it will be able to do. I was hoping someone may be able to give me some advice.

I work in the agricultural industry, our farm machinery is controlled through a number of unconnected (WIFI or 4g) screens X30s. They control the steering, job allocation and product application. The assigned'jobs' are uploaded via a USB and completed 'jobs' are then downloaded. The USB is then unplugged from the X30 and taken into the office and the data is downloaded. 
We are constantly transferring data via USB's.

I am wondering whether a RSPi with a cellular module could be used as a cellular connected dropbox USB stick?

I.e. we would upload the files to and from dropbox, which would appear through cellular connection on the PI, which is connected via USB to the X30 as a 'slave' device.

Is this achievable with pretty basic skills from the RSPi perspective?

Many thanks

James

Comment: You should know that Stackexchange is for more specific questions and not "is this possible" questions.. There are a few examples and tutorials online about integrating DropBox with the Raspberry Pi, so should be simple enough, some 3G dongles do work with the RPI.

Comment: Vincent, apologies I was not aware of the specifics of this forum. Many thanks

Comment: Most Pi do not support acting as a USB device; they have USB ports for plugging in devices.  Look for USB OTG support.  OTG allows a USB port to be either host (accepting a device) or a device (connected to a host).

Comment: @James Your idea is possible, what I mean is that you need to ask specific questions IE: I cannot get my RPi to correctly connect to DropBox. All the luck with your project, I love agricultural projects.